# echo a message while a file is uploading

Tags: php

I want to echo a message reading "file uploading" while the file is uploading but the message is only being echoed after it has finished uploading, is there another way of dong this?

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target))

  {
     echo "file uploading";
     header("location:somewhere.php?uploaded")
  } 

else echo "oops!";
```

Comment: you can't with php, you have to use javascript in the page where is the  form in, for example showing a "loading gif"

Comment: Not directly. You will have to make an asynchronous upload instead; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are encountering right now is the necessity to do something *asynchronously*. Synchronous is what you are doing right now, i.e. firing a new request and thereby uploading the picture, which only allows showing the message *after* the request.

You can upload the image in the background and display a loading gif or something like that on the page using [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [jQuery](http://jquery.com). This allows you to show the message *while* uploading.

For a good introduction to jQuery, check [these videos from the new boston](http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=32). Specifically for AJAX, check out [episode 101 and following](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=32&number=101).

Comment: Thanks for the links I will check them out

Answer (score 3):

It only prints after the file is uploaded because that's when you're PHP script is executed, **after** the file is uploaded.

A solution is to use the PECL [upload progress](http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress) package, though this means installing an extension to PHP, which you may or may not be able to do with your host.

Answer (score 1):

First thing. The **location** `header();` function should be `L` (in upper case in `Location:` ) then, **Always** use absolute URI's inside a header(); like..

`header("Location: the_location_url");` OK? Good!

Now, about displaying `Loading..` you should use the `sleep();` function to delay any ongoing process by entering number of seconds inside it, as show here`sleep(05);`

Now, about your code:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $target))

  {
     echo "file uploading";
      sleep(05);
     header("Location: the_location_url")
  } 

else echo "oops!";
```

Comment: @nickb tell me about it, seems everybody thinks so, not just me lol

Comment: "Your code is a real teresko. It is bad, real bad." "OK? Good!" No need to talk down to the OP like that.

Comment: It was a joke from almost a decade, I'll remove it